# Image full width of browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a header image on a wordpress site I'm creating that needs to be the full width of any browser.

The code already existing on the parent theme is:

```
background: url("/test/wp-content/themes/Howtopassyourexams.com/Theme/images/page-header-bg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 7px 10px -10px #000;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
height: 300px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
```

There is also a second style sheet on the theme thats used and inherits most of the styles from the parent stylesheet, where the image CSS on that stylesheet is:

```
background: url("/test/wp-content/themes/Howtopassyourexams.com/Theme/images/page-header-bg.jpg");
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
```

I'm not sure why the heading image has two css codes in two stylesheets, but thats the way the theme came, and I'm not a expert in this so that may be normal.

The image is sticking to the original size (1369x325px) even when the width is changed to 100% and therefore cutting some of it out on a smaller browser.

Any help where I'm going wrong would be great, site address: http://biobreak.co.uk/test/services/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule in the first stylesheet actually sets the size of the background image with the word `cover`.

The second rule's `width: 100%;` setting only sets the width of the surrounding element, not the background image itself (which remains unchanged `cover`).

So you have to add

```
background-size: 100%;
```

to that second rule.

Answer (score 0):

Two way, the first one is to put the image in a `relative` div and then give the image the following

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

or just use the `vw` unit

```
img {
  width: 100vh;
}
```

if you're a background image just use `background-size: 100%;`

Comment: Thank you I will give it a go